# cannot convert value of type 'nsindexpath?' to expected argument type '[nsindexpath]'

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I want to delete a row from my tableView using deleteRowsAtIndexPaths, the codes I use to obtain the NSIndexPath of the specific row are as follow:

```
    let pointInTable: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(sender.bounds.origin, toView: self.tableView)

    let cellIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)
```

But then I got the error as suggested in the title when I put down cellIndexPath for deleteRowsAtIndexPaths. I get a sense that it might be about an array type of NSIndexPath but I'm not sure exactly how I should construct my codes. Please help thanks!

Comment: It expects `[NSIndexPath]` so you'll have to pass it as an array: `[indexPath]`: `if let indexPath = cellIndexPath { tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)`

Comment: try this : `if  let cellIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable) { self.tableView. deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([cellIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)}`

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem in this instance:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPath, with: .fade)
```

resolved it like this:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```